# Check if an object is dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, templates

I have this class template called `Manager` that is responsible for adding, querying and deleting objects. Here's the header file:

```
template<class T>
class Manager
{
public:
    Manager() {}
    ~Manager();

    void addObject(const std::string &name, T object);
    void removeObject(const std::string &name);
    void removeAllObjects();

    unsigned int getNumObjects() const;
    T getObject(const std::string &name) const;

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, T> _objects; //name, object
};
```

Now say I have a Manager object of int pointers, and add heap allocated integers, like `myManager.addObject("heap allocated", new int(3))`

Is it possible to know in `Manager::removeObject()` whether each inserted object is heap allocated or not, so then I know if I need to call `delete`?

Comment: Consider smart pointers instead.

Comment: No, and even if it was, you'd still have to know whether it was allocated by `new`, `new[]`, or `malloc()` (so you can deallocate it with `delete`, `delete[]`, or `free()`).

Comment: Short answer: no, it’s not possible. There are ways around that if you’re willing to change the API, by forbidding the class to accept heap-allocated values altogether (by constructing the value internally).

Comment: You can redefine global new, new[], delete. delete[] operators to keep track of object creation.

Comment: I'm not sure if smart pointers is what I need. They are deleted when going out of scope, which is what I'm trying to avoid. I want my cached objects to be available up until my Manager instance goes out of scope. If I'm wrong, can you post an example of using smart pointers with Manager?